# A curious family of integrals that give $\pi$

Tags: integration

I have noticed experimentally that:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\color{red}{x}}{x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x+1} \,dx=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{8}},\tag{1}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\color{red}{1-x^2}}{x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x+1} \, dx=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{4}},\tag{2}$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\color{red}{1+x-x^2}}{x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x+1} \, dx =\color{blue}{\frac{3\pi}{8}}.\tag{3}$$
So slight variations in the numerator *always* seem to produce something like $n\pi$, where $n$ is a rational number.
At [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4736889/a-curious-family-of-integrals-that-give-pi) I have asked what the exact relationship is between $n$ and the numerator of the integrand, to which Quanto  has responded with a general formula:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ax^2 +b x + c}{x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x+1} \, dx
=\frac\pi8(c+b-a)+\frac\pi{3\sqrt3}(a+c).\tag{4}$$
However, is it necessary for the denominator to remain fixed? Not really. The following integral is formula (34) in this list of [$\pi$ formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html):
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\color{red}{16x-16}}{x^4-2x^3+4x-4}\,dx=\color{blue}{\pi}.\tag{5}$$
Notice that the denominator is different. But again, a slight variation in the numerator and it *still* produces something like $n\pi$:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\color{red}{x^2-x-1}}{x^4-2x^3+4x-4}\,dx=\color{blue}{\frac{3\pi}{16}}.\tag{6}$$
The fact that the denominator is not the same suggests that a further generalization is possible.

Here is my question: **is it possible to characterize the integrand $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ in such a way that by simple inspection we can say $I=n\pi$? Or in other words, what should be the relationship between the coefficients of the numerator and the denominator for the integral to yield $n\pi$?**

Comment: If Q is a real polynomial with no real roots, it is not unlikely that one finds as antiderivative a sum of arctan, by part.frac.dec.

Comment: Yes, but very few rational combinations of arctan of rational numbers give rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: The following is a general formula for the BBP integral for $\pi$ (see eq. (34) in the [list of $\pi$ formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html)):
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^4-2x^3+4x-4}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{16}\color{red}{(2a-c)}+\frac{\ln{(3-\sqrt8)}}{\sqrt32}\color{red}{(b+c)}+\frac{\ln{(3-\sqrt8)}}{\sqrt8}\color{red}{a}.$$
From this formula, we can deduce that the integral will yield rational multiples of $\pi$ when $b$ and $c$ are opposite to each other and $a=0$.

Comment: However, this formula is still far from being the ultimate generalization since it does not take into account the coefficients of the denominator.

Comment: The latter denominator ($x^4-2x^3+4x-4$) factors as $(x^2-2)(x^2-2x+2)$; the original denominator is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, though, which I think makes it a much more interesting case.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, although if you look at one of the [answers on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4736909), you can see that the source of $\pi$ is still arguably the integral of $1/(1+y^2)$ "in disguise."

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía Yes, basically. For example, given $\int dt/(2-\sin 2t)$ we can substitute $y=2\tan t + 1$ to get the integral $\int dy/(y^2 + 3)$ which again is an arctangent integral. There are many ways to "disguise" the arctangent integral. For example, $$\int_0^1 {-15x^2+14x-1\over 25x^6-70x^5+59x^4-14x^3+x^2+1}\,dx = {\pi \over 4}$$ can be evaluated using the substitution $y=-5x^3+7x^2-x$. The denominator looks like a mysterious irreducible polynomial at first glance.

Comment: @TimothyChow: Sorry, I misunderstood what you said. That's why I deleted my comment. I believe that in this type of integrals that result in pi, we cannot do without arctan, right?

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía Yes, I think so. The natural logarithm of a complex number can give us $\pi$ but I think that we can always rewrite such expressions using arctan.

Comment: @TimothyChow: Regarding the Quanto solution, either their solution is wrong, or I am missing something, because when I make $x=\tan{\frac{t}{2}}$, the integrand does not reduce to $\frac{\cos{t}}{2-\sin{2t}}$. I get this: $\frac{2\cos^2{\frac{t}{2}}\cos{t}}{2-\sin{2t}}$. Have you verified it yourself? I am waiting for Quanto to respond to this doubt.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía I get the same thing Quanto got. It looks to me that you forgot that $dx = dt/(2\cos^2(t/2))$.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably too optimistic to hope for a complete characterization of such integrands.  For some context, see for example [Some New Formulas for $\pi$](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/articles/Almkvist.pdf), by Gert Almkvist, Christian Krattenthaler, and Joakim Petersson, *Experimental Mathematics* 12 (2003), 441–456.  On the first page you can find the formula
$$\int_0^1 {28x^6 − 56x^5 + 28x^4 − 97x^3 + 97x^2 − 6 \over
(x^3 − x^2 + 2)^3}\,dx = {\pi\over 8},$$
but more importantly, they describe some general methods for searching for such formulas, and make it clear that their list is likely far from comprehensive.

A related paper is [Integral Proofs that $355/113 > \pi$](https://www.austms.org.au/wp-content/uploads/Gazette/2005/Sep05/Lucas.pdf) by Stephen Lucas, *Australian Mathematical Society Gazette* 32 (2005), 263–266, which concerns itself with finding integrals such as
$$\int_0^1 {x^8(1−x)^8(25+816x^2)\over 3164(1+x^2)\,dx}={355\over 113}-\pi.$$
Again, Lucas describes several empirical methods for searching for such formulas, but was not able to find a systematic characterization of all such formulas.

Comment: $$\int_0^1{1\over x^3-x^2+2}={3\log2+\pi\over10}, \int_0^1{x\over x^3-x^2+2}={-6\log2+\pi\over20}$$ so $$\int_0^1{x+1\over x^3-x^2+2}={\pi\over4}$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That suggests that by doing some arithmetic with the integrands, we can obtain more intimidating integrands that still yield $\pi$. The following one comes from adding integrands (2) and (5) with different denominators: $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2(1-x)(x^5-5x^4-10x^3-4x^2+8x-8)}{x^8-2x^6-2x^5+9x^4-2x^3-16x^2+12x-4}=\pi.$$

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía The paper by Almkvist et al. describes how they used lattice-basis reduction methods to find suitable [integer linear relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm). This is a standard technique in experimental mathematics nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of these. They reduce via partial fraction decomposition to inverse trig functions or logarithms in which the unusable parts cancel out except $\pi$ or some other constant depending on the choices of $P(x), Q(x)$.

Certain choices of denominator polynomials $Q(x)$ leads to an infinite series as done by Krattenthaler [3] via beta function. Any polynomial will not work even if it factors. It has to be in the form $z+x^a(1-x)^b$. Unfortunately, it does not generalize to multivariable polynomials. For example [2]:

$$\int_0^1 {x^4-5x^2+16 \over
48+x^2(1-x^2)^2}\,dx =  \frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{18}$$

Which can be put into the above form with substitution $x=y^{1/2}$

Attempts to generalize  this for higher order constants are given by [1] requiring harmonic numbers.

[1]https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.03086

[2] https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3919892

[3] https://www.plouffe.fr/simon/articles/Almkvist.pdf